# How to read encrypted database field using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a project where some database table fields need to be encrypted. The way this will be done is using Microsoft SQL Server built-in encryption/decryption function:

```
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('PASSPHRASE',‘text’)

DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('12',password)
```

So to insert data the SQL will be like this:

```
insert into login_details(uid,username,password) values(1,'smith',EncryptByPassPhrase('12',’XXX’))
```

And to read data the SQL will be this way:

```
select uid,username, DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('12',password) as Password from login_details
```

So my question is how I can I make use of this in Hibernate using my existing OR mappings?  I'm using JPA Annotations.
Is there an easy way to do this with JPA annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how you might do that. But from what I've read, ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE uses triple-DES. So you might encrypt the data yourself and persist it as is with Hibernate. Here's how it would look like to make it transparent (except for queries, obviously)

```
@Entity
public class LoginDetails {
    @Column(name = "password")
    private byte[] encryptedPassword;

    @Transient
    private String password;

    public void getPassword() {
        if (password == null) {
            password = CryptoUtils.decrypt(encryptedPassword);
        }
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.encryptedPassword = CryptoUtils.encrypt(password);
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

where `CryptoUtils` would be responsible for storing the secret key and encrypting/decrypting using triple-DES (which is natively supported in the JDK : see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher)

Just make sure to test it and make sure that your decryption is able to decrypt what SQL-Server has encrypted, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you are looking for org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer

```
@Column( name = "pswd" )
@ColumnTransformer( write="EncryptByPassPhrase('12',?)", read="DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('12',pswd)" )
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Reviving an old thread, but I was having a similar requirement and found that [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html) has some very nice support for this.

Once Jasypt configured, it's as easy as adding a "`@Type(type="encryptedString")`" annotation:

```
@Column(name = "password")
@Type(type="encryptedString")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```